# Virtual Keyboard in Linux/GTK

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, gtkmm, virtual-keyboard

I have a simple interface (Can be touch-based or can be operated by mouse clicks). When I select a text box, a virtual keyboard should pop up. I have done a little digging, and `xvkbd` looks nice. X11 is the only dependency, which is fine! However, I do not want to install a keyboard in a system and call it issuing commands or set environment variables. I want the keyboard to be a part of the application I make, and it should pop up when I run the application and select a text box, and under no other circumstances. As I gather, coding a virtual keyboard from scratch is not the easiest of tasks. If there is something I could use in my C++ application, it would be really nice. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Check matchbox-keyboard, it should do what you need with gtk.

Taken from its [README](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/matchbox-keyboard/tree/README)

> Embedding
>
> You can embed matchbox-keyboard into other applications with toolkits that support the XEMBED protocol ( GTK2 for example ).
>
> See examples/matchbox-keyboard-gtk-embed.c for how its done.

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment! However, there seem to be many complications regarding this keyboard. I posted a question on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12802147/1062484) and I hope I get an answer soon!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QX11EmbedContainer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qx11embedcontainer.html), if you have access to Qt. If not, you can embed the xvkbd's window yourself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395044/embed-an-app-into-a-window) how).